# Register for content-available push notifications only

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

For which `UIRemoteNotificationType` should I register when I only want to send 'silent' push notifications which trigger a background refresh? This is for a non-newsstand app.

Comment: any luck? Ideally for silent push it would be great to obviate explicit user approval

Answer (score -1):

=You can register for the two notification types:

```
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert and UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
```

using a pipe operator like this

UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge

If no sound is required you could leave out the sound type (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound).

Hope this helps.